# Display Multidimensional array via ajax in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

The form displays data from DB for the entry to be edited. One of the columns is a 2D Array and I do not know how to pass the data.

Tried the normal AJAX display codes

The data coming via COntroller is:
res.credential looks like

```
[
    [
        "Facebook","x11111111",
        "q1111111","w11111111"
    ],
    [
        "Linkedin","x222222222",
        "q222222","w222222222222"
    ],
    [
        "Twitter","x333",
        "q3333333","w3333333"
    ]
]
```

The AJAX looks like:

```
$('.password-edit-btn').on('click', function (){
    var client_sel = $(this).data('id');
if (client_sel) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/get_password_data?id="+client_sel,
        success: function (res) {
            if (res) {
                console.log(res.credential);
                $("#edit-password-client").empty(); 
                $("#edit-password-client").append('<option>'+ res.client +'</option>'); 
                $('#edit-password-remarks').val(res.remarks);
            }

// The problematic area is below
            if (res.credential) {
                $.each(res.credential, function (key, value) {
                    console.log(value)
                    $(".add-hf-accounts").append()
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

});

Simply display the data in the div with class "add-hf-accounts".

Comment: where do u pass that array??? ajax to the controller or ajax to view

Comment: Ajax to View. "Simply display the data in the div with class "add-hf-accounts".

Comment: Show your router code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(res.credential, function (key, value) {

  for(var i=0;i<value.length;i++)
  {
    if(i==0)
    {
        $(".add-hf-accounts").append('<h2>'+value[i]+'</h2>');
    }
    $(".add-hf-accounts").append('<li>'+value[i]+'<li>');
  }
});
```

Try It...Will be Work Fine

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the help guys.

The problem was in parsing. I had to use JSON.parse and then it worked beautifully. Below is the final working answer.

```
if (res.credential) {
                $.each(JSON.parse(res.credential), function (key, value) {
                    $(".add-hf-accounts").append('<div class="hidden_event"><div class="form-group col-sm-2"><label>Account</label><select class="form-control" name="account[]"><option value="'+ value[0] +'"> '+ value[0] +'</option></select></div><div class="form-group col-sm-3"><label>URL</label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Accoutn URL" name="url[]" value="'+ value[1] +'"></div><div class="form-group col-sm-3"><label>Username</label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" name="user[]" value="'+ value[2] +'"></div><div class="form-group col-sm-3"><label>Password</label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password[]" value="'+ value[3] +'"></div><div class="form-group col-sm-1 acc-btn"> <br><button class="btn btn-danger remove " type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button></div></div>');
                });
            }
```